# 'Unable to convert instance of type 'Google.Android.Material.TextView.MaterialTextView' to type 'AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.Toolbar'.'

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin.forms

After upgrading the Xamarin Forms version from 4.5.+ To 5.0, the following exception appeared. Any suggestions how to solve it ??

Exception Image
[image: Exception Image]

Comment: please do not post code or exceptions as images.

Comment: @Jason How will people then understand what exactly happened? The error code may be the same, but in different places. Because of this, solutions can be completely different??

Comment: Because search engines can't index an error message when it is posted as an image, making it useless for helping anyone else with the same problem in the future.  Because images are useless if you're behind a firewall that prevents them from loading, or are on a limited bandwidth connection, or are visually disabled and rely on screen readers.  Because code is inherently text based and can be easily pasted as text in SO.  There is nothing in the image you posted that could not be conveyed as text.

Comment: Really. You're right. I admit I'm wrong. Thx for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `Toolbar.axml` and `Tabbar.axml` then update your class to `AndroidX` class name mapping [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/class-mappings)

Comment: Thank u very much. U right.

Answer (score 0):

Well the error is well explained

```
'Unable to convert instance of type 'Google.Android.Material.TextView.MaterialTextView' to type 'AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.Toolbar'.'
```

You are trying cast an object with a different object. Simply, think like this

```
you are trying to cast a car into a carpet
```

So, it's not possible. That's why the error occured.

Comment: I understand you have not looked at the screenshot I provided? For I am not converting one class to another, but Xamarin.